# Git push origin master after performing hard reset

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-push

I recently performed a `hard reset` to another branch, as I was unable to get my `master` branch back to a working state. I did this using the command:

```
git reset --hard masterBackupBeforeMerginDateDepositReceived04-01-2017
```

(i.e. to the branch where the particular feature I had broken was still working)

I then ran:

```
git commit -m 'commit after getting adds/omits working again'
```

having checked that the broken feature was working again on my local `master` branch- it was, so I wanted to commit this again to be sure I had that working state saved.

I then ran

```
git push origin master
```

to push the `master` branch to the server again, so that the now fixed feature should start working again on the live version. However, after running this `push`, Git displayed a message I've not seen before:

> To git@bitbucket.org:abc/xyz.git
>    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:abc/xyz.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

It seems that Git is not happy with me pushing an 'old' version to the server, when there is a 'newer' version currently on the server... How can I force the server to accept my `push` of the 'old' version (which is currently the `master` branch on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

simply add the force option `-f`

`git push -f origin master`

[Git Push Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--f)

Comment: I tried this, but Git gave me an error message saying: `error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:moonhub/moon.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`, so it seems that the `push` failed... any other suggestions?

Comment: Can I just replace `master` with another local branch, and then push this? How would I do that?

Comment: the `-f` option should resolve that message. I am not sure why you are getting that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use reset and then force the push it can mess up other people who have pulled the version you don't like.

After the broken version has been pushed to the remote repo, it is best to recover using **revert** instead of reset.

Revert will add changes on top of the bad commit, such that the new version looks the way it did earlier.  Then when you push you are just pushing new changes which fix the mistakes that were pushed earlier.

For example

```
git revert HEAD
```

will add new changes which undo the effect of the most recent commit.
See the revert documentation for more details on undoing multiple commits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing `git revert 36ceff5f071b4c45f56a6c4bca523d0e9b5c1bc8` i.e. to a previous commit, but it gave me an error stating that it couldn't revert: `error: could not revert 36ceff5... dateDepositReceived sticks after change to deposit value
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'`

Comment: I have another branch in which the feature still works- can I just replace my `master` branch with this other branch? How would I do that?

Comment: You can reset your local master branch to the working version with the reset command.   e.g.  checkout master  and then do git reset --hard good-branch-name      Then you must use the -f option mentioned by Rafael above.  However, if other users have pulled the bad version then their repos will be out sync and they will not be able to push changes they make.  Are there other users using this branch?

Comment: No, I am the only person working on the development of this software... so just checkout local `master`, then do `git reset -- hard masterBackupAfterGettingAddsOmitsWorkingAgain`? where `masterBackupAfterGettingAddsOmitsWorkingAgain` is the branch name where this feature is still working? When do I use the `-f`?

Comment: the -f is required when you push, as mentioned in Rapfael's post above.  git push -f origin master

Comment: The -f means force, and it tells git that you want this pushed even though it changes the history recorded in the remote repo.

Comment: I tried `git push -f origin master`, but Git gave a message saying: `error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:moonhub/moon.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.` , so it seems that the `push` failed...

Comment: Can I just replace local `master` with another local branch, and then push this? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push a local branchx to remote master branch, you can try `git push -f origin branchx:master`.

If you have already rename the local branchx to master, you can use `git push -f origin master`.